# Mouseclick deselects programs unless 'run as administrator'

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Whenever I click, using either of my laptop's mice, on any program, the program moves to the background.  I cannot click in the program's window, anywhere.  I can click on the desktop, and when I right-click a program a desktop icon and select 'run as administrator', the mouse works.  I cannot click on the start-bar icons, the start menu....  Not sure why this is happening.  Any ideas?

-update-
When I am accessing the program that is being run as administrator, I am able to click on start-menu and task-bar icons.

-update-
Ran multiple antimalware apps and windows update.  This is a fresh 7 Pro 64 install.